# How to check if method exists when arguments are given by the tuple?

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-hana

I would like to check whether a function with the given signature exists. The twist is that the signature is given by the tuple:

```cpp
#include <boost/hana/type.hpp>
#include <boost/hana/tuple.hpp>
#include <tuple>
namespace hana = boost::hana;

struct LibA {
   static int foo(int, float, double) { return 1;}
};

struct LibB {
   static int bar(float, float, float) { return 2;}
};

template<typename Lib, typename... Args>
int call(Lib, hana::tuple<Args...> args) {
   auto hasFoo = hana::is_valid(hana::unpack)(args, Lib::foo);
   auto hasBar = hana::is_valid(hana::unpack)(args, Lib::bar);

   static_assert(hana::if_(hasFoo || hasBar, true, false), "Cannot find both positional and named version of the functor.");
   return(hana::if_(hasFoo, 
          hana::unpack(args, Lib::foo),
          hana::unpack(args, Lib::bar)
   ));
}


int main() {
   int i; float f; double d;
   call(LibA(), hana::make_tuple(i, f, d)); //compile error: 'bar' is not a member of LibA
   call(LibB(), hana::make_tuple(f, f, f)); //compile error: 'foo' is not a member of libB
}
```

The `hana::is_valid` returns a compile error rather than handle it as it is supposed to. I understand it is caused by the indirection - it only validates the call to the `hana::unpack`, which is ok, but not the nested call to the `Lib::foo`. Is there a walkaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer inside the function template definition to `Lib::x` that is not an *immediate* template expansion context, so SFINAE doesn't apply there and hence you get a compiler error.

Only invalid types and expressions in the *immediate* context of the function type and its template parameter types can result in a deduction failure.

An alternative working solution:

```
struct LibA {
    static int foo(int, float, double) { return 1; }
};

struct LibB {
    static int bar(float, float, float) { return 2; }
};

template<typename Lib, typename... Args>
auto call(Lib, hana::tuple<Args...> args) -> decltype(hana::unpack(args, Lib::foo)) {
    return hana::unpack(args, Lib::foo);
}

template<typename Lib, typename... Args>
auto call(Lib, hana::tuple<Args...> args) -> decltype(hana::unpack(args, Lib::bar)) {
    return hana::unpack(args, Lib::bar);
}

int main() {
    int i; float f; double d;
    call(LibA(), hana::make_tuple(i, f, d));
    call(LibB(), hana::make_tuple(f, f, f));
}
```

In the above, that trailing return type with `decltype` is an *immediate* template expansion context and SFINAE works as expected there.